# Mocking class properties while using 'autospec=True' in python

Tags: python, properties, attributes, mocking, subclassing

I wish to mock a class with the following requirements:

- The class has public read/write properties, defined in its `__init__()` method
- The class has public attribute which is auto-incremented on object creation
- I wish to use `autospec=True`, so the class's API will be strictly checks on calls

A simplified class sample:

```
class MyClass():
    id = 0

    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=1.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.id = MyClass._id
        MyClass.id +=1

    def calc_x_times_y(self):
        return self.x*self.y

    def calc_x_div_y(self, raise_if_y_not_zero=True):
        try:
            return self.x/self.y
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            if raise_if_y_not_zero:
                raise ZeroDivisionError
            else:
                return float('nan')
```

I need for the mock object to behave as the the original object, as far as properties are concerned:

- It should auto-increment the id assigned to each newly-created mock object
- It should allow access to its `x,y` properties
  But the mock method calls should be intercepted by the mock, and have its call signature validated

What's the best way to go on about this?

**EDIT**

I've already tried several approaches, including subclassing the `Mock` class, use `attach_mock()`, and `mock_add_spec()`, but always ran into some dead end.

I'm using the standard [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html#mock-mocking-and-testing-library) library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no answers are coming in, I'll post what worked for me (not necessarily the best approach, but here goes):

I've created a mock factory which creates a `Mock()` object, sets its `id` property using the syntax described [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.PropertyMock), and returns the object:

```
 class MyClassMockFactory():
     _id = 0

     def get_mock_object(self, *args,**kwargs):
        mock = Mock(MyClass, autospec = True)
        self._attach_mock_property(mock , 'x', kwargs['x'])
        self._attach_mock_property(mock , 'y', kwargs['y'])
        self._attach_mock_property(mock , 'id', MyClassMockFactory._id)
        MyClassMockFactory._id += 1
        return mock

     def _attach_mock_property(self, mock_object, name, value):
         p = PropertyMock(return_value=value)
         setattr(type(mock_object), name, p)
```

Now, I can patch the `MyClass()` constructor for my tests:

```
class TestMyClass(TestCase):
     mock_factory = MyClassMockFactory()

     @patch('MyClass',side_effect=mock_factory.get_mock_object)
     test_my_class(self,*args):
         obj0 = MyClass()
         obj1 = MyClass(1.0,2.2)
         obj0.calc_x_times_y()
         # Assertions
         obj0.calc_x_times_y.assert_called_once_with()
         self.assertEqaul(obj0.id, 0)
         self.assertEqaul(obj1.id, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to dig up an old post, but something that would allow you to do precisely what you would like to achieve is to patch `calc_x_times_y` and `calc_x_div_y` and set `autospec=True` there, as opposed to Mocking the creation of the entire class.

Something like:

```
@patch('MyClass.calc_x_times_y')
@patch('MyClass.calc_x_div_y')
test_foo(patched_div, patched_times):
my_class = MyClass() #using real class to define attributes
# ...rest of test
```